# Does apt-get enforce cryptographic authentication and integrity validation by default for all packages? (debian, ubuntu)

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, debian, apt, package-manager

Does the built-in `apt` package manager in Debian-based systems require successful cryptographic authentication and integrity validation for all packages?

My understanding was that software downloaded with `apt-get` packages would be cryptographically verified because the repo would sync pgp-signed manifest files on `apt-get update`.

However, I stumbled on an article today that suggested that unsigned packages are accepted by default on all major Debian-based Operating Systems by the contents of `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg`

```
root@disp2019:~# cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
# dpkg configuration file
#
# This file can contain default options for dpkg.  All command-line
# options are allowed.  Values can be specified by putting them after
# the option, separated by whitespace and/or an `=' sign.
#

# Do not enable debsig-verify by default; since the distribution is not using
# embedded signatures, debsig-verify would reject all packages.
no-debsig

# Log status changes and actions to a file.
log /var/log/dpkg.log
root@disp2019:~#
```

Indeed, this does not look good.

Do Operating Systems with `apt` require valid signatures from a pinned set of keys stored to the `apt-key` keyring on *all* packages by default? Or are these signatures just treated as optional by default?

Comment: See also https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2018/02/21/attacks-against-secure-apt-repositories/

Comment: See also https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Verifying_Software_Signatures#Attacks_in_the_Wild

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285635/how-is-the-authenticity-of-debian-packages-guaranteed

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/990143/how-does-apt-get-check-the-integrity-of-the-downloaded-files-it-receives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of cryptographic validation here:

- Apt supports that each developer signs the package with its own key, and to validate that on package install. This is what this file refers to ***and is not used*** (currently) by Debian, Ubuntu, etc.
- The repository manifest is cryptographically signed with a repository key (see `apt-secure(8)`) and that validates the referred packages. **That is used by all of them**.

So, there is a cryptographic validation, just not the one that file refers to.