# Does snapd enforce cryptographic authentication and integrity validation by default for all packages? (debian, ubuntu)

Tags: authentication, ubuntu, integrity, debian, package-manager

Does the `snapd` package manager in Debian-based systems require successful cryptographic authentication and integrity validation for all packages?

I know that [software downloaded with `apt-get` packages must be cryptographically verified](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246425/does-apt-get-enforce-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation-by-de) because the repo's manifest files (synced with `apt-get update`) are cryptographically signed.

But what about `snapd`?

Do Operating Systems with `snapd` require valid signatures from a pinned set of keys on *all* packages by default?