# Does pacman enforce cryptographic authentication and integrity validation by default for all packages? (arch linux)

Tags: authentication, linux, integrity, package-manager

Does the built-in `pacman` package manager in Arch-based systems require successful cryptographic authentication and integrity validation for all packages?

I know that [software downloaded with `apt-get` packages must be cryptographically verified](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246425/does-apt-get-enforce-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation-by-de) because the repo's manifest files (synced with `apt-get update`) are cryptographically signed.

But what about `pacman`?

Do Operating Systems with `pacman` require valid signatures from a pinned set of keys on *all* packages by default?

Answer (score 1):

Pacman on Arch Linux enforces signature verification by default:

> Package security

> Pacman supports package signatures, which add an extra layer of security to the packages. **The default configuration**, SigLevel = Required DatabaseOptional, **enables signature verification for all the packages on a global level**: this can be overridden by per-repository SigLevel lines. For more details on package signing and signature verification, take a look at pacman-key.

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#Package_security