# Does yum enforce cryptographic authentication and integrity validation by default for all packages? (CentOS, RHEL)

Tags: authentication, linux, centos, package-manager

Does the `yum` package manager in CentOS/RHEL-based systems require successful cryptographic authentication and integrity validation for all packages?

I know that [software downloaded with `apt-get` packages must be cryptographically verified](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246425/does-apt-get-enforce-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation-by-de) because the repo's manifest files (synced with `apt-get update`) are cryptographically signed.

But what about `yum`?

Do Operating Systems with `yum` require valid signatures from a pinned set of keys on *all* packages by default?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CentOS & RHEL-based systems require valid gpg signatures on all packages in the default repositories, which provides cryptographic authentication and integrity for all packages.

This can be confirmed by checking for the line in the repo's cooresponding file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`

```
gpgcheck=1
```

#### History

CentOS & RHEL use RPMs to distribute packages. The tools for managing RPMs have supported PGP signature functionality [since at least v2.0.1](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/CHANGES), which was released sometime [in or before 1996](http://rpm.org/timeline.html).