# Does flatpak enforce cryptographic authentication and integrity validation by default for all packages? (fedora)

Tags: authentication, linux, integrity, package-manager

Does the `flatpak` package manager in Fedora-based systems require successful cryptographic authentication and integrity validation for all packages?

I know that [software downloaded with `apt-get` packages must be cryptographically verified](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246425/does-apt-get-enforce-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation-by-de) because the repo's manifest files (synced with `apt-get update`) are cryptographically signed.

But what about `flatpak`?

Do Operating Systems with `flatpak` require valid signatures from a pinned set of keys on *all* packages by default?

Comment: see also https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak.github.io/issues/520

Comment: This seems to be about flatpak with flathub. Please correct me if it's not using flathub. I asked about it here: https://github.com/flathub/flathub/issues/1498 which was closed unresolved (however with links to issues which are similar and still open).

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179175/are-snap-and-flatpak-apps-safe-to-install-are-they-official-approved-or-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As of 2023, **flatpak does not provide cryptographic authentication** on any of the packages it downloads.

This was originally submitted as a [feature request](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak-builder/issues/435) in 2015, but the devs either don't understand the security risk or they don't care enough about security to implement it.

- https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak-builder/issues/435